# How do I use the value of the form in the script function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the data that is being inputted at the name and the quantity to be used in the function orderPizza(), I am quite confused about how to do it

```js
function orderPizza() {
  var x = document.form["PizzaForm.Cname"].value;
  var y = document.form["PizzaForm.qPizza"].value;
  var z = parseFloat(12.99);
  var totalPrice = y * z;
  alert("Name: " + x + "Quantity ordered: " + y);
  var answer = prompt("Would you like to place this order", " ");
  if (answer == '1') {
    document.write("Your order has been placed");
  } else if (answer == '2') {
    document.write("Your order has been cancelled");
  } else {
    document.write("Invalid Entey");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form name="PizzaForm">
    Name: <input type="text" name="Cname"><br><br> Quantity of Pizza: <input type="text" name="qPizza"><br><br>
    <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="orderPizza" />Sumbit
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `getElementsByName` method, and set `onclick` to `orderPizza()`

```js
function orderPizza() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("Cname")[0].value;
var y = document.getElementsByName("qPizza")[0].value;
  var z = parseFloat(12.99);
  var totalPrice = y * z;
  alert("Name: " + x + "Quantity ordered: " + y);
  var answer = prompt("Would you like to place this order", " ");
  if (answer == '1') {
    document.write("Your order has been placed");
  } else if (answer == '2') {
    document.write("Your order has been cancelled");
  } else {
    document.write("Invalid Entey");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form name="PizzaForm">
    Name: <input type="text" name="Cname"><br><br> Quantity of Pizza: <input type="text" name="qPizza"><br><br>
    <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="orderPizza()" />Sumbit
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are wrong:

```
var x = document.form["PizzaForm.Cname"].value;
var y = document.form["PizzaForm.qPizza"].value;
```

You can't combine the form and input names into a single property like that. The input is a property of the form object.

```
var x = document.form["PizzaForm"]["Cname"].value;
var y = document.form["PizzaForm"]["qPizza"].value;
```

Comment: This helped me figure it out. Thanks